# How to prevent VSTS from generating NuGet packages when validating a Pull-Request?

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

I have an account set up on VSTS.

Every time a new build is triggered, the pipeline builds the solution and publishes NuGet packages.

[image: Build pipeline]

The problem is that it also builds the solution and publishes the packages when a pull request is created, as shown in the picture below:

[image: Builds 1.2.0.41 and 1.2.0.39]

In my case, I have 2 builds (1.2.0.41 and 1.2.0.39) that have been generated before the PR has been approved and caused packages to be published.

**Question**

How can I prevent VSTS from generating NuGet packages when a PR is created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [task conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/process/conditions?view=vsts). `and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))` should run the task if it's *not* a pull request.